# Django - accessing foreignkey's attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using the Django generic User model and I also added this additional model:

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

Now, I have a user who's username is

```
testUser
```

and I want to access testUser and see what all photo's testUser has and delete all photos for testUser. I want to do this in the python shell. I was thinking doing something like this:

```
python manage.py shell

from app.models import UserImages
a = UserImages(user=testUser)
a.photo.all.delete()
```

but when I try to do

```
a = UserImages(user=testUser)
```

or

```
a = UserImages(user__username=testUser)
```

it gives an error saying

```
name 'testUser' is not defined
```

. How do I get the variable 'a' to be the testUser object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `auth.User` object:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> testUser = User.objects.get(username='testUser')
>>> from app.models import UserImages
>>> a = UserImages(user=testUser)
```

or pass in a string when querying just `UserImages`:

```
>>> a = UserImages(user__username='testUser')
```

Comment: @ScorrWoodall hm strange, okay thanks. Can you see this question and see why I am getting results which I am not expecting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030128/django-imagefield-files-not-showing-up