# Django - ImageField files not showing up?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

This is my models.py:

```
class UserImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

and this is my view which uploads images:

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()

    return render(request, 'image.html', {'form': form})
```

and this is my view which displays user's images:

```
def displayImageView(request):
    user = request.user
    img = UserImages.objects.filter(Q(user__username=user))
    return render(request, "displayImage.html", {"img": img})
```

and this is my displayImage.html template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for image in img %}
    <img src="{% static image.photo.url %}" alt="" />
{% endfor %}
```

and when I go to the URL which loads the template, it displays four images. I remember that while testing the uploadImageView, I uploaded 4 images for the viewer. The location Django saves the images was

```
/home/images/static
```

and I went to that folder and deleted two images. I then refreshed the template page and it still displayed 4 images rather than two, so then I figured that I had to delete it from the actual database rather than the folder. I then did

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from app.models import UserImages
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> a = User.objects.get(username='testUser')
>>> b = UserImages(user=a)
>>> b
<UserImages: UserImages object>
>>> b.photo
<ImageFieldFile: None>
```

amd as you can see, only one ImageFieldFile shows up for the user who I uploaded 4 images for. How come I can only see one?

EDIT:

my UploadImageForm() is just this:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImages
        fields = ['photo']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
>>> b = UserImages(user=a)
>>> b
<UserImages: UserImages object>
>>> b.photo
<ImageFieldFile: None>
```

This code snippet is creating a new instance of `UserImages`, setting the `user` attribute to the object `a`. It is not searching the database. Since you haven't attached any images to this new instance, `b` is `None`.

To search, you need to do this instead:

```
>>> b = UserImages.objects.filter(user=a)
```

You also shouldn't upload anything to the same folder that is pointed to by `STATICFILES_DIRS`, as this folder is managed by django and your files here will be overwritten. I hope `/home/images/static` isn't listed here.

User uploads are saved in a subdirectory pointed to by `MEDIA_FILES` and accessed using `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: hm okay, so two questions. -1- if I want to delete, say two of the 4 images which is in b, then how would I do that? -2- I tried b = UserImages.objects.get(user=a) but it gave an error saying 'MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one UserImages -- it returned 4!' How come it gave that error but b=Userimage.objects.filter(user=a) returned 4 as well but there was no error?

Comment: Yes, because you are using `get`, which will raise an exception if multiple rows are returned (you noticed I used `filter` in my answer). This is just how `get` works.

Comment: hm, /home/images/static IS listed in STATICFILES_DIRS. If i'm not supposed to place any files in the same folder that is pointed to by STATIC_DIRS, then how am I supposed to load my css? Where are my CSS files supposed to be saved?

Comment: CSS files are different than images. STATICFILES_DIRS are for files that are shipped as part of your application; needed to make your application work (this includes CSS files, images, javascript, etc.) Files which your users upload go in a different folder called MEDIA_FILES and are accessed using MEDIA_URL. The reason being the `collectstatic` command manages the static files and will collect all your static files, from all applications and put them in STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: ahhh, okay, makes sense, thanks! but how am I supposed to load media files then? because right now to view user uploaded images, I just load static in the template and do {% img src='static 'relativePathToImage' %} but if I just store uploaded media to MEDIA_ROOT, then how do I load it and view images in it inside the template relative to the folder pointed to in MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: There is a `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` tag you can use in your templates, and while you are developing code, you can use [this snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user) to serve media files.  Django only provides helpers for static files, and the handling of media files is left up to you :)

Comment: hm, confusing lol okay I will read up on all of that now.. Anyways though, now that b is a list of multiple UserImages objects, how do I delete all of them? I tried "for image in b: image.delete()" but it didn't do anything, how come?

Comment: it did do something. Check your database.

Answer (score 1):

When you save images in the database they will be saved in there as well as in a new location in your `/static/` directory, etc..  Usually Django attaches a `image_1.jpg` for example if the image was originally `image.jpg`.

Do your images have a `many-to-many` relationship to the `User` model? Earlier, you said that there were 4 images saved to the `User`, then you said 1.  Your `UserImages` model has one field, so possibly you are not looping through it correctly in the `terminal shell` in order to check all images.  Perhaps it needs to be `b.photos.all()` if `b = UserImages(user=a)` or something to that extent?